# Read numpy array(matrix) fast from text file

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matrix

I am having trouble to read a matrix from a text file to a numpy array very fast without any unnecessary copying.

The format is the following:

```
3   
1   -1  6   5   9   7   0   -7  
0   -5  -5  3   -7  -2  4   3   
-2  -9  -5  6   6   -2  -9  9   
-7  -3  3   -3  3   8   8   -8  
9   3   5   2   -2  4   6   5   
-1  -8  7   -4  -1  3   7   4   
0   -4  -8  -3  2   6   2   -2  
-1  8   6   5   9   8   0   6
```

The first line (3) indicates the size of the matrix i.e here it is 2^3 = 8x8 matrix

Each column is separated with a `\t` character and each line is separated with a `\n` character.

I have tried `numpy.loadtxt()`, I can specify the row delimiter, skip the first row (the 3) but then I need to specify a column delimiter. Can anyone help please?

Comment: `np.loadtxt(<path-to-file>, skiprows=1)` *should work*, what is it giving you?

Comment: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.loadtxt.html Read the docs.

Comment: In `loadtxt`, `delimiter` splits columns.  You can't specify a row delimiter.  That should be a straight forward load.

Answer (score 1):

@juanpa the loadtxt(path, skiprows=1) works perfectly, thank you so much!